# Pivoting Long Data to Wide data with Counts and Percentages in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I need to get a set of data from a long format to a wide format, showing numbers of counts and the relative percentages. Below is some dummy data that is similar to my situation:

```
df <-tibble::tribble(
                  ~YEAR,                    ~Volunteers, ~retained,   ~n, ~Rel.Percentage,
                            2016,                            "LA",       "N",  51,                             "7%",
                            2016,                            "LA",       "Y", 685,                            "93%",
                            2017,                   "Victorville",       "N",  12,                            "16%",
                            2017,                   "Victorville",       "Y",  66,                            "84%",
                            2018,                 "Inland Empire",       "N",  33,                            "13%",
                            2018,                 "Inland Empire",       "Y", 227,                            "87%",
                            2019,                   "Kern County",       "N",   5,                             "7%",
                            2019,                   "Kern County",       "Y",  69,                            "93%",
                            2020,                       "Military",       "N",  61,                            "20%",
                            2020,                       "Military",       "Y", 243,                            "80%",
                            2017,                            "LA",       "N",  59,                             "7%",
                            2017,                            "LA",       "Y", 645,                            "93%",
                            2016,                   "Victorville",       "N",  15,                            "16%",
                            2016,                   "Victorville",       "Y",  64,                            "84%",
                            2019,                 "Inland Empire",       "N",  32,                            "13%",
                            2019,                 "Inland Empire",       "Y", 221,                            "87%",
                            2017,                   "Kern County",       "N",   7,                             "7%",
                            2017,                   "Kern County",       "Y",  73,                            "93%",
                            2016,                       "Military",       "N",  63,                            "20%",
                            2016,                       "Military",       "Y", 241,                            "80%"
                  )


wide.test <-df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from = c(`Rel.Percentage`) )
```

Which gives an offseted table with NAs, but I want the numbers and relative percentages to show side by side.

```
new.wide <-df[, !(names(df) %in% c("n"))] %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from = `Rel.Percentage`)
```

which gives me a neater table with the percentages, but doesn't show the n's

I've also tried:

```
newer.wide <-df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from = c(`Rel.Percentage`, n) )
```

But the issue with this solution is that the n's are now on their own set of columns which makes this largely unreadable. I'm hoping to get the numbers to be alongside their relative percentage, in parentheses, if possible, to show the underlying number next to the relative percentage.

Comment: Not sure if you already had ur data as a `tribble`, but if you made it for just this example then check out the `dput` function, it prints ur data so anyone can copy-paste it.

Comment: my bad, I made it just for this example. The data is originally a dataframe, would you think I should convert it or keep it in the format? tbh I'm going to export it into a LaTeX file right after I create this wide format

Comment: Well, I meant it more as a convenience for you. `dput` makes a string that you can copy-paste into your question. Then anyone can copy that into their `R` session. I personally prefer a `tibble` over a `data.frame`. The printing is much cleaner and it comes with other features like `nesting` (see `tidyr::nest`). If you are making a LaTeX table, I would recommend looking at the `xtable` package. This is designed to convert data in R to tables in LaTeX.

Comment: thank you, I'll think about using tibbles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate your data before the pivot. Use something like `paste0(df$n, " (", df$Rel.Percentage, "%)")` to create a new variable and then use that variable in the `values_from` argument.

EDIT:
to make it more so like a complete example:

```
#this pastes the characters into the "fixed" column with both n and the percentage
df$fixed <- paste0(df$n, " (", df$Rel.Percentage, ")")

#this creates the table in a wide format with percentages across the years, while dropping the unnecessary columns for a cleaner look
df.wide <-df[, !(names(df) %in% c("n","Rel.Percentage"))] %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from =fixed )
```

Thus, this can be exported into a LaTeX table for easy report writing :

```
print(xtable(df.wide, type = "latex"), file = "df_wide.tex")
```

Comment: will this solution maintain the indexing? I wouldn't want to have the wrong percentages/n's in with the wrong years or volunteers

Comment: actually your answer is giving me the error: ```Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.```

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz it would. `df$neat <- paste0(df$n, " (", df$Rel.Percentage, " %)")` that worked for me and you can see how they match up.

Comment: Could you edit your response into a working example? If so, I'll give you the "answer"